# Nfs client on Window7

Tags: fedora, nfsclient

I have setup Nfs server on fedora19 and started all the service like rpcbind,nfs-lock,nfs-server,nfs-idmap 
when i type in  terminal"sudo vi /usr/sbin/exportfs" i get o/p

```
         [root@balkrishna balkrishna]# sudo vi /usr/sbin/exportfs
         /home/balkrishna/nfs_server
         192.168.213.0/24
```

And my exports file contain

```
      /home/balkrishna/nfs_server (rw,sync,all_squash,anonuid=12345,anongid=23456)
```

Now i want it to connect to window 7(fedora is installed in Vmware), so when i type

```
     C:\Users\Balkrishna>mount 192.168.213.156:/home/balkrishna/nfs_server Z:
```

in command prompt i get following error

```
               C:\Users\Balkrishna>mount 192.168.213.156:/home/balkrishna/nfs_server Z:
                Network Error - 53

              Type 'NET HELPMSG 53' for more information.

              C:\Users\Balkrishna>NET HELPMSG 53

              The network path was not found.
```

i even tried switching off the private firewall but still above error exist 
I have tested my NFS server in another fedora, the NFS-client of another fedora was able to mount the server, but in windows7 i am not able to mount, Please help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MS' page ([Mounting an NFS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754350.aspx)) the correct syntax to mount a NFS share is:

```
mount \\nfs_server\share g:
```

This would make yours:

```
mount \\192.168.213.156\home\balkrishna\nfs_server z:
```